# Generating id in my table based on sub groups

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem generating my id in my [newtable]. It must increment for every new group from sub.
Any suggestion?
My own thinking is that maybe I can put case statement in the nested select?
I need the select in my insert statement. the table called newtable is empty and I want to populate it with data from main and sub. the insert is left out here because its the select that need to be fixed.

```
     SELECT 
      (SELECT NVL(MAX(newtable.ID), 0)+1 AS MAX_VAL FROM newtable)AS ID
      ,main.ID as ID_PLACE
      , main.place
      , sub.somedata 
    FROM main 
    LEFT JOIN sub on main.ID = sub.ID
```

some data would look like this

```
    sub
    id  somedata
    972 fdsfds
    972 fdsfds
    972 fdsfds
    972 fdsfds
    972 fdsfds
    972 fdsfds
    973 opfg
    973 kl
    973 uu


            main
    id  place
    972 2564
    973 1122


            newtable
    id  id_place    place   somedata
    1   972         2564    fdsfds
    1   972         2564    fdsfds
    1   972         2564    fdsfds
    1   972         2564    fdsfds
    1   972         2564    fdsfds
    1   972         2564    fdsfds
    2   973         1122    opfg
    2   973         1122    kl
    2   973         1122    uu
```

Comment: Your example is not clear, what do you mean by every new group from sub? Add some more records in your newtable example, where exactly id should change.

Comment: Yes that's true, I have added some more record. 
I can do with replacing this pice 
(SELECT NVL(MAX(newtable.ID), 0)+1 AS MAX_VAL FROM newtable)AS ID
with main.id and use the same id as in main, but this is a one time thing and I would like the id's to start from 1 if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and share the results (not tested)

```
with tab as (SELECT NVL(MAX(newtable.ID), 0)+1 AS MAX_VAL FROM newtable)
    SELECT ((select max_val from tab) + 
           dense_rank() over (order by main.ID)) ID
          ,main.ID as ID_PLACE
          , main.place
          , sub.somedata 
        FROM main 
        LEFT JOIN sub on main.ID = sub.ID
```

Edit:
Removed partition by clause, not required.